# Wix: Only accept InstallDirs without spaces

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I need a setup that has to be installed into a path that should not contain any spaces. I could write a custom action and abort the setup if it contains any spaces but this would be a bit to dramatic.

Is there a way I can subscribe to a event an disable the "Next" button if a path with spaces was selected?

Comment: This seems like a really arbitrary requirement. Why is it needed? Are you just hiding a more insidious underlying issue?

Comment: @BrianSutherland The software itself is provided by a third-party company and doesn't support running from a location that contains spaces. We licensed the software for distribution and need to ensure that it only gets installed in a valid directory. This is definitively a workaround but we don't have access to the sources to fix it right now.